# Lifecycle - fetch data only after loading complete

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that needs to wait for the user's token to be validated first before fetching data. Right now, my component only renders when `authLoading` is `false` but I'm fetching my data in `componentDidMount` so sometimes the token is not validated yet and I get an unauthorized error. How should I refactor this so everything should wait for `authLoading` to finish?

```
componentDidMount() {
  // if (!authLoading) { <----- Sometimes the component mounts and the fetchData function doesn't get called
    this.fetchData();
  // }
}


render() {
  const { authLoading } = this.props;

  if (!authLoading) {
    return (
      <Component1 />
    );
  }
  else {
    return null
  }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note, this could be a problem further up the tree. Generally speaking, you don't wanna render your app if a user isn't logged in. So somewhere, in the entry point, you'll wanna check for token, and if it's not there, redirect users to the login page. This is a very general comment, without knowing exactly how you're handling authentication

Comment: Can you use a functional component instead? Using a hook would make this trivially simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to fetch your data only once, but also only after `this.props.authLoading` becomes false.

Check out [componentDidUpdate()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), which will allow you to update any time your props change.

Your implementation might look something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!this.props.authLoading && prevProps.authLoading) { // tokens just loaded!
    this.fetchData();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert your component to be a functional component then using hooks would me this simple.

```
const MyComponent = ({ authLoading }) => {
  const [authLoaded, setAuthLoaded] = useState();
  useEffect(
    () => {
      fetchData();
      // process data
      setAuthLoaded(/* some value based on fetched data I assume */);
    },
    [authLoading], // triggers effect anytime value of `authLoading` changes
  );

  return authLoaded ? <Component1 /> : null;
};
```